# Answering "Have you got" questions with "I do"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, have-got

For the question *"Have you got any ice cream?"* which is correct:

1. Yes I do
2. Yes I have

or inversely

1. No I don't
2. No I haven't got any

Comment: Somewhat anecdotal relative: "Do you speak english?" "yes, I speak.."

Comment: Related: [Can one answer “Have you got…?” with “Yes, I've got.”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46230/can-one-answer-have-you-got-with-yes-ive-got)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since the OP changed the tense in his question, I have updated my answer:

1. > *Yes, I have.*

   or

   > *Yes, I have got some ice cream.*
2. > *No, I haven't.*

   or

   > *No, I haven't got any ice cream.*

Comment: So to follow it through, the first one in full would be "Yes I do I have ice cream"?

Comment: No. The short form is just "Yes I do" and the long form is "Yes I have ice cream" or "Yes I have some ice cream".

Comment: Sorry Mehper my question was confused, I've updated it to what I was trying to ask originally

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: The answer below is more faithful to actual usage. Answers need supporting references.

Answer (score 9):

> For the question "Have you got any ice
>   cream?" which is correct:
>
> Yes I do
>
> Yes I have

The traditional answer would be "yes I have" but "yes I do" is common in American usage and is gaining usage in the UK too.

Comment: Though this is doubtless correct, answers on ELU need supporting references.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably both are correct:

> 'Have you got any ice-cream?'
>
> 'Yes, I **have** ***got*** ice-cream.' -OR- 'Yes, I **do** ***have*** ice-cream.'

In Australia both "I do" and "I have" are used and essentially mean the same thing.

It is the same for the negative forms:

> 'No, I **have not** ***got*** ice-cream.' -OR- 'No, I **do not** ***have*** ice-cream.'

Comment: In the USA, the same. Either _I do_ or _I have_ is acceptable; the first because _do_ is short for _do have_, which is what _have got_ means. The second because _have_ is the auxiliary for _have got_. Speaker's choice. [As I've said before](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76141/15299), in the USA _have got_ has a special meaning -- it's replaced most of the occurrences of the 'possess' sense of _have_, and muddies the waters of the rest, as here.

Answer (score 0):

Fact is, the more streamlined you can get your students to speak, the better. Short answers first. Yes, I do. No, I don't. I do or don't. Yes, I have. This is clearly more educated and proper and not what's in usage with young people today. As a teacher, I tell my students to read the room. I teach them both, whether they hear the do you have form or have you got form, they decide. I try to make them aware of regional differences, but social media, T.V. and the internet has clearly had an impact. Most importantly, you get them communicating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "This is clearly more educated and proper and not what's in usage with young people today." I have no idea why you would think that elision *isn't* in use today with "young people". You really should elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The pedantic answer is that, if the question is

> Have you got . . . ?

the answer should be

> Yes, I have.

while, if the question is

> Do you have . . . ?

the answer should be

> Yes, I do.

However, given that these two questions are nowadays largely interchangeable, many people who are used to the latter form may 'hear' *Have you got* as *Do you have* and spontaneously give the answer that matches it, *Yes, I do*. While it could be argued that this is, by some strict criteria, incorrect, it carries no risk of miscommunication whatsoever, and it is highly unlikely that anybody would be bothered by it.

Answer (score -2):

"Yes, I do" is essentially short for "yes, I do got some ice cream", which clearly doesn't make sense.

"Have you got?" = "yes, I have"
"Do you have?" = "yes, I do"

Just because people say something doesn't make it correct.

Comment: The unspoken complication here is that when people respond to the question "Have you got any ice cream?" with the single word "Yes," there's no way of discerning whether they are using "Yes" in their own minds as a truncation of the proper form "Yes, I have got some ice cream" or of the improper form "Yes, I do got some ice cream." In fact, the only way of to determine whether they are using "Yes" correctly or not, is to respond to their "Yes" by asking them directly, "Do you mean 'Yes, I have got some ice cream" or 'Yes, I do got some ice cream?'"

Comment: "Got any ice cream?" would be another common variant of the question, and "yes, I do" sounds as good a response to that as "yes, I have".