# Can one answer "Have you got...?" with "Yes, I've got."?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, have-got, grammaticality

As an American in Europe I often get questions about the British "have got" which is hard for me to answer since I have little feeling for what is correct. E.g. someone today asked me:

> If someone asks me, "Have you got a pencil" and I say, "Yes, I've got." Is this incorrect?

I told him, "Yes, that is incorrect, you should either say, 'Yes, I have' or 'Yes, I've got a pencil."

I know, as an American speaker, I would answer, "Yes, I do" but in a British context, is my answer above correct?

Comment: This would be the violation of verb valency http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29

Comment: There are lots of grammatically and colloquially valid responses, but I'd guess the most *likely* response is a mumble along the lines of "sure" followed by some rummaging through a bag.

Answer (score 8):

No native speaker of BrE would normally say *Yes, I’ve got* in that context. The reply might, as you say, be  *Yes, I have* or *Yes, I’ve got a pencil* depending on the circumstances. A further possibility, in BrE as well is in AmE, is certainly *Yes, I do.*

Comment: Also "Yes I've got one", "Yes", "Sure", or simply handing over a pencil. :-)

Comment: Isn't "Yes, I do" the reply to "Do you have a pencil"? It sounds a bit strange to me here.

Comment: I agree. It depends, as always, on the circumstances, and on the relationship between the speakers.

Comment: @ Tim: I think various combinations might be found, depending on . . .

Comment: In American English, I think some speakers reserve "Yes, I have" for the use of "have" as an auxiliary verb signifying completed action. ("Have you gotten a birthday present for Mom yet?" "Yes I have.") This is why "Yes, I do" is a natural response to the construction "Have you got ... ?" in the sense of possession.

Comment: @Tim: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if we use "Have" as an auxiliary verb in the question, in the answer we should use it.

E.g. :                           Have you got a pencil ? Yes, I have.

We should not use auxiliary verb "do" in the answer for this case. On the contrary, if we use : 
                                 Do you have a pencil ?

Then its answer will be :        Yes, I do.

(MTesol Phan phi Phong3p)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the way American English works.